# Dúvida angularjs com array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Como faço para pegar apenas os `id` e `key`?

```
{
  "type": "champion",
  "version": "6.3.1",
  "data": {
    "1": {
      "id": 1,
      "key": "Annie",
      "name": "Annie",
      "title": "a Criança Sombria",
      "info": {
        "attack": 2,
        "defense": 3,
        "magic": 10,
        "difficulty": 6
      }
    },
    "2": {
      "id": 2,
      "key": "Olaf",
      "name": "Olaf",
      "title": "o Berserker",
      "info": {
        "attack": 9,
        "defense": 5,
        "magic": 3,
        "difficulty": 3
      }
    },
    "3": {
      "id": 3,
      "key": "Galio",
      "name": "Galio",
      "title": "o Sentinela da Amargura",
      "info": {
        "attack": 3,
        "defense": 7,
        "magic": 6,
        "difficulty": 3
      }
    }
  }
```

O array está na variavel `content`, usando `{{content.data[1]}}` consigo isso:

```
 {
   "id": 1,
   "key": "Annie",
   "name": "Annie",
   "title": "a Criança Sombria",
   "info": {
     "attack": 2,
     "defense": 3,
     "magic": 10,
     "difficulty": 6
   }
 }
```

Mas gostaria de capturar apenas `id` e `key`. De que maneira posso fazer isso?

Comment: `content.data.id` ?

Comment: Tentei mas n funcionou, colocando content.data[1].id funciona, mas não qria fazer de 1 por 1, tem como usar um "for" pra resolver isso?

Comment: Estou montando uma solução.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/w0cL5vy9/

Comment: @BrunoBrito Você vai trabalhar com esses valores no HTML ou no Controller?

Comment: Por enquanto no HTML

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se for utilizar apenas no HTML é só fazer um ng-repeat dessa forma:

```js
angular.module('App', [])
    .controller('MyCtrl', [
            '$scope',
            function(
                $scope
            ) {
                $scope.content = {
                    "type": "champion",
                    "version": "6.3.1",
                    "data": {
                        "1": {
                            "id": 1,
                            "key": "Annie",
                            "name": "Annie",
                            "title": "a Criança Sombria",
                            "info": {
                                "attack": 2,
                                "defense": 3,
                                "magic": 10,
                                "difficulty": 6
                            }
                        },
                        "2": {
                            "id": 2,
                            "key": "Olaf",
                            "name": "Olaf",
                            "title": "o Berserker",
                            "info": {
                                "attack": 9,
                                "defense": 5,
                                "magic": 3,
                                "difficulty": 3
                            }
                        },
                        "3": {
                            "id": 3,
                            "key": "Galio",
                            "name": "Galio",
                            "title": "o Sentinela da Amargura",
                            "info": {
                                "attack": 3,
                                "defense": 7,
                                "magic": 6,
                                "difficulty": 3
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }              
                }
            ])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="App" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <ul ng-repeat="item in content.data">
    <li>{{item.id}} -- {{item.key}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Se precisar utilizar direto no Controller é só utilizar o forEach:

```
  angular.forEach($scope.content.data, function(item){
      console.log(item.id +" - "+item.key);
  })
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode iterar sobre a lista e transformar a informação para o padrão que desejar.

Por exemplo, o código abaixo retorna o seguinte array:

```
[{"id":"1","key":"Annie"},{"id":"2","key":"Olaf"},{"id":"3","key":"Galio"}]
```

```js
var app = angular.module('sampleApp', []);

app.controller('SampleController', function ($scope) {

  $scope.fonte = {
    "type": "champion",
    "version": "6.3.1",
    "data": {
      "1": {
        "id": 1,
        "key": "Annie",
        "name": "Annie",
        "title": "a Criança Sombria",
        "info": {
          "attack": 2,
          "defense": 3,
          "magic": 10,
          "difficulty": 6
        }
      },
      "2": {
        "id": 2,
        "key": "Olaf",
        "name": "Olaf",
        "title": "o Berserker",
        "info": {
          "attack": 9,
          "defense": 5,
          "magic": 3,
          "difficulty": 3
        }
      },
      "3": {
        "id": 3,
        "key": "Galio",
        "name": "Galio",
        "title": "o Sentinela da Amargura",
        "info": {
          "attack": 3,
          "defense": 7,
          "magic": 6,
          "difficulty": 3
        }
      }
    }
  }

  $scope.forEachMap = [];
  
  angular.forEach($scope.fonte.data, function(value, key) {
  $scope.forEachMap.push({id: key, key: value.key});
  });
  
});
```

```html
<html ng-app='sampleApp'>
  
  
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="SampleController">

      
     
      {{forEachMap}}


    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```